# Malware and Viruses on Mac

Tags: mac, security

In most of the places, the Mac computers are protected against the malware and viruses, but not all of them. This means that even Mac computers may be infected with these dangerous things.

How can we understand that mac computer is infected with a malware or virus ? This is very easy for the computer with windows operating system because antivirus programs detect all dangerous things in the computer. On the other hand, anybody do not advise me to install a Mac protecter program because most of them are malware itself.

Comment: Are you asking how a Mac can get a virus, how you can determine if a Mac has a virus, or are you asking about getting anti-virus software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally upto you to keep a watch for any suspicious activity on your Mac to detect presence of a malware or virus. If you are tech savvy and follow news around Apple, you should be able to hear about any newly discovered threat. Apple software engineering team is quite prompt and quickly releases patches fixing any newly uncovered serious iOS and macOS threats.

It is highly recommended to always keep your OS up to date.

Comment: Actually, I intended to watch a movie via a website, and when I clicked the movie, new page appeared like a pop-up and they told me that your Mac computer was infected with a virus. It seemed to be unreal. I think the main objective of that page is to worry me and to make me click that page to clear the viruses which makes the computer be really infected. However, I wanted to make sure, so I asked this question thank you so much.

Comment: I don't know what website you visited to watch the movie, but **legit** websites generally doesn't show such behaviour. Only access trusted and popular websites. I believe you encountered a pop up asking you to install MacKeeper. That's a pretty well know malware for sure. Refrain from installing it, you'll have a hard time getting rid of it. The main objective of such pages is generally to get you to install malware or some paid app.